# Server 2016 Hyper-V: VMs Not Booting After Previously Working

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I'm running Hyper-V on Server 2016 Datacenter, at home. I've created a number of Windows 10 VMs, both Pro and Enterprise. While I was creating these VMs, I didn't run into any problems. I was able to boot into the OS, log into the computer, and configure it as normally. However, for each one of these VMs, at some point when I tried to start the VM, I would run into SEVERE slow down issues. Often times I couldn't get to the log on screen again. It would simply sit at the black screen with the Hyper-V logo, while the spinning dots would go on spinning endlessly. This is a recent issue. Within the past week. I didn't previously have this problem, but I also haven't been using Hyper-V heavily on this install until recently. My OS is fully updated (which hopefully isn't the problem...)

I have made no absolutely no hardware changes and no changes to the configuration of the VMs. Usually after, restarting my computer of the VMs a few times, this issue would show up and the VM s would become unusable. Again, these VMs initially worked just fine. They started up quickly and were very responsive.

I've tried creating new VMs, using different ISOs, and even uninstalling and reinstalling the Hyper-V module and management tools. All with no luck. I would really like to avoid reinstalling my host OS if that could be helped, but right now that's all I can think of, though I have no idea if that would even work since I don't have a clue where the problem lies. Below my hardware and VM configuration are linked below (won't let me embed a screenshot). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Hardware and VM configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZstM6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took time to examine the Hyper-V logs, even though I suspected it might not be the problem. After examining the logs and confirming that Hyper-V wasn't the issue, I started to re-evaluate what I thought could be the cause, and I realized it could be storage based. I copied my VMs from my D Drive (HDD) to my C Drive (SSD). Once I did that they started to work perfectly. I then re-examined the logs and looked for storage events. Under Applications and Service Logs -> Microsoft -> WIndows -> StorDiag, I found a long list of errors. Specifically StorDiag EventID  504, which I've copied below. I'm not exactly sure what it means, but after discovering this, I attempted to copy a large file back to the D Drive and discovered absolutely horrible write times. This seems to be the problem. Now I have to figure out the cause (if anyone knows what this is, I'd love to hear from you).

I don't know the protocol on this forum is, but I'll mark this as solved and open up a new thread if I can't figure it out.

---

```
Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-Storage-ClassPnP/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-StorDiag
Date:          6/12/2019 00:53:30
Event ID:      504
Task Category: Class
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Device I/O control request
User:          computer\Administrator
Computer:      my.computer.net
Description:
Completing a failed IOCTL request.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-StorDiag" Guid="{F5D05B38-80A6-4653-825D-C414E4AB3C68}" />
    <EventID>504</EventID>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>200</Task>
    <Opcode>101</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x800000040000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-06-12T04:53:30.284022800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>997253</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="1784" ThreadID="2336" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Storage-ClassPnP/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>my.computer.net</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-4150441485-2800377868-2508223801-500" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="DeviceGUID">{D393DD4A-6271-DA94-0AA1-DD1DE3F36251}</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceNumber">0</Data>
    <Data Name="Vendor">NULL</Data>
    <Data Name="Model">ST2000DL003-9VT166</Data>
    <Data Name="FirmwareVersion">CC32</Data>
    <Data Name="SerialNumber">            6YD0GE9Q</Data>
    <Data Name="IrpStatus">0x80000011</Data>
    <Data Name="IoctlControlCode">0x7c088</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```